# How show in map circle image or circle marker with image?

Tags: google-maps, nativescript

I use nativescript vue and display the google map.

I can show the image on the map in the marker, but I cannot show the image of the circle on the map.

How can i do this?

I use ns sidekick in windows 10 and i create apps to android and ios.

I show the image like this:

```
var mapView = args.object;
var marker = new GoogleMaps.Marker();

marker.position = GoogleMaps.Position.positionFromLatLng(36.799441, 10.178554);
marker.title = "Tunis";
marker.snippet = "Tunisia";
marker.userData = {index: -1};


let imgSrc = new ImageSource();
imgSrc.fromBase64("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU.......kJggg==")

let image = new Image();
image.imageSource = imgSrc;
marker.icon = image;

mapView.addMarker(marker);
```

Comment: You want to show an image over the map, is that what you meant?

Comment: no, show circle image or marker with circle image

Comment: The plugin already allows you to use custom image on marker, it could be circle or whatever shape you like.

Comment: Image in my app square and i should show the circle. Props borderRadius don`t work.

Comment: You should get a circle image, marker doesn't support any other attributes.

Comment: I know that this is real, I can see it at https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/issues/316, but I don’t know how to use it

Comment: Good. How can I edit an image to keep it round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this plugin to make my own custom marker [nativescript-bitmap-factory](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-bitmap-factory). If you want a very custom element for your markers something like this can help you to achieve that

Comment: this really in android apps only. In ios i can't replace pixel to transparent pixel. I'm still looking for a solution.